# LastPass causing incorrect email address to be saved in new user form

Tags: users, control-panel

*I already have a solution for this but am writing it up in case others run into the same issue.*

After creating a new user, *my* email address was showing up as the username of the new user. (This site uses email addresses as the username; `useEmailAsUsername` is set to true in config/general.php.) Here's how it looked in the user list:

[image: Admin email showing up as new user username]

It also showed up on the user page:

[image: User card]

I thought I might have stumbled on a bug related to `useEmailAsUsername`. Silly me. Craft support (hi, Brad) wasn't able to reproduce it and suggested it might be an auto-fill browser extension misbehaving. Sure enough…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After disabling my password manager, LastPass, my email address stopped sneaking into the username field. Upon closer inspection, here's what was happening:

After filling out the new user form and clicking 'Save,' you are prompted for your password. **THIS** is where LastPass misbehaves, or more accurately, does what it's designed to do but not very helpfully. It not only fills the password input, but replaces the contents of the 'Username' field with *your* email address (that is, the email address associated with the login stored in LastPass). It's easy to miss this, however, with the transluscent white overlay.
[image: Craft password dialog - LastPass inserts wrong email address]

### Solution

Configuring LastPass to not fill forms on the new user page isn't helpful, as you likely want it to enter your password when prompted. The best solution I could come up with is to clone my Craft login, delete the email address / username, and add 'New User' to the label. Now when prompted for the password I can select *that* login and avoid overwriting the new user's email address.

Comment: Oh man... that's sneaky.  Thanks for posting in case someone else runs into it.

Comment: Also just to note - this same thing happens with the 1Password browser extension as well. Has caught me out a few times...